# How do you implement an app autoupdate feature from scratch?

Tags: architecture, mobile, networking, application-design, desktop-application

I am trying to imagine how Google Chrome automatically updates but have some questions:

1. Is this against Apple's terms of service? I feel like I've seen somewhere that Chrome for MacOS isn't in the Apple Store because of this. Not sure.
2. How is it swapping out its runtime?
3. Is it possible to autoupdate on iOS/iPad?

Basically I just would like to know how it works, and from there I can figure out the platform-specific implementation details (I'm thinking of doing this in Swift for iOS and MacOS).

From my imagination, it seems that for this to work, there would be a daemon polling the network for updates. Once it finds an update is ready, it downloads *something* (what does it download?). Does it just download the whole new app binary? Or some sort of patch?

Then to get the autoupdate, you must close and reopen the app. What this means is that the app icon you click on actually just pings the daemon, which looks for the "last download" of the app. And then the daemon runs the latest download. That's pretty much it.

So there is a "shell" of an app, which is the app icon. Then there is a "daemon" app, which stays around. Then there is the "real" app, which is what gets loaded as the browser, for example. So 3 apps at least.

Is this how it works? If not, what actually does happen?

Also, can you do this same sort of thing on iOS/iPad/Windows?

Comment: Come on, guys, this is a high-level conceptual question, clearly expecting only a high-level conceptual answer, which makes it IMHO focussed-enough to be answerable. No need to "close-vote" any such question just because a "deep-dive" into the details would become too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already figured out the general idea of how auto-update works, so I'll just answer your specific questions.

> Is this against Apple's terms of service?

Very likely yes, because allowing apps to download and execute new binaries without going through the app store approval process would be a security hole.

> Is it possible to autoupdate on iOS/iPad?

App stores (regardless of platform) generally have their own auto-update mechanism, so there is no need to build your own. You simply submit a new version of your app to the store and it automatically gets pushed to devices.

> Does it just download the whole new app binary? Or some sort of patch?

Depends on the app. Smaller / monolithic apps that have a single binary will likely get fully replaced on an update. Larger apps (such as your favorite IDE) will typically consist of several smaller modules and updates might only affect some of those modules.

> So there is a "shell" of an app, which is the app icon. Then there is a "daemon" app, which stays around. Then there is the "real" app, which is what gets loaded as the browser, for example. So 3 apps at least.

Again, depends on the app. There could be the 3 components that you described, or in the simplest case, there could only be one: the "daemon" could be part of the main app, and when there is an update, it could just download and run an installer which reinstalls the app.